# Image has no texture even when I added materials

Tags: rendering

When I tried to render I get no texture.
[image]

As shown there.
this problem affects all of my blender files.
So i updated blender to latest version to see if that would make a difference.
But it did not.
Also I don't have a holdout feature [image]
And emission shaders look like this
[image]
all of my files render like this regardless of what texture I apply.
Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: Looks like your object is set to holdout. Make sure this is unchecked https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pNQy.png